# T-SQL Batch execution from a .net application, time out when the batch has too many calls to the same stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, timeout, batch-processing

I would like some information regarding what's happening when I call a batch like:

```
SET @ClosedMonthCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #migratedClosedMonths);
WHILE(@ClosedMonthCount > 0)
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @IteratedAbsenceConfigId = PayrollAbsenceConfigId ,@ClosedMonthId = PayrollClosedMonthId FROM #absencesToMigrate

    EXEC @Value = [dbo].[AbsenceConfigArchive_GetValueByColumn] 'zcbfrm', @IteratedAbsenceConfigId, @ClosedMonthId;

    EXEC [dbo].[AbsenceConfigArchive_InsertSync] @ClosedMonthId, @IteratedAbsenceConfigId, N'DaysPaidByCompany', @Value

    SET @ClosedMonthCount = @ClosedMonthCount - 1

END

GO
```

As you can see this loop will call 2 stored procedures many times; this batch goes into a .net c# program under a transaction.

Will take a lot of time, depending on connection timeout can also the batch fail with a timeout.

If I execute this batch in SSMS on a query file under a begin tran ... commit the batch will execute quite fast (huge time difference).

If I execute the batch in .net program (ADO) without transaction is working as fast as I execute the batch in SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)!

Can you please explain what's the difference and what can I do to my ADO objects (connection, transaction) to achieve the same performance as executing the batch in SSMS?

Comment: Hello, have you try recompile those procedures? maybe ado-sql connection doesn't catch up properly

Comment: I forgot to add @ClosedMonthCount going to 0, the code is actually an example for the case (is different from the one from production)

Comment: Hard to know without seeing execution plans, but also unclear why you need a `WHILE` loop, why not rewrite the procedures to do the whole thing in batch?

Comment: If you need a cursor (which is rare), then just USE a cursor rather than the more error-prone equivalent that you attempt. Use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is generally a logic fault - which is likely a contributing problem.

Comment: Is the result of `SELECT @@OPTIONS` the same between SSMS and your ADO app? Identical queries (to the byte level, including whitespace) will have different cached plans if their @@OPTIONS are different, and some option values are called "plan affecting" because they change the plans output by query planner. You can almost always count on the default setting of `ARITHABORT` being different in SSMS than every other DB connection library.

Comment: Neither of the stored procedures have a name that suggests they delete from the `#absencesToMigrate` temp table, since one is called "get" and the other is called "insert". So at first glance your `select top 1` seems likely to just select the same row over and over... and even that's not guaranteed because of the lack of an `order by`, as SMor pointed out. If one of them *does* do a delete then at least one of them violates SRP *and* the design is fragile, using the #absencesToMigrate table as a globally available variable within the outermost scope.